# Trouble with calling methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math

class Vector():

    vA = [3.183, 7.627]

    def magnitude(vector):
        sum = 0
        i = 0
        while i < len(vector):
            sum += vector[i]
            i += 1
        return math.sqrt(sum)

    def unitVector(vector):
        print( 1 / (magnitude(vA) * vA))
```

I'm attempting to code some linear algebra and calculate the unit vectors for the vector 'vA' stated above. When I run the code I get `NameError: global name 'magnitude' is not defined`. I do not understand why I am having an issue with simply calling one function from another.

I'm a beginner with python and I'm assuming I have a misunderstanding about classes and functions, but I have looked through the documentation and cannot find the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Instance methods need a self parameter

Comment: Sidenote: the numpy library is probably better to do linear algebra calculations

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code:

- `def magnitude(vector)` should be `def magnitude(self, vector)`
- `def unitVector(vector)` should be `def unitVector(self, vector)`
- `magnitude(vA)` should be `self.magnitude(vA)`

EDIT:

A better way of writing your class would be to use OOP concepts in Python, so you do not have to pass vector as a function argument if you make it an instance variable.

Your class can be rewrote like this:

```
import math

class Vector():

    def __init__(self, vector):
        self.vector = vector


    def magnitude(self):
        sum = 0
        i = 0
        while i < len(self.vector):
            sum += self.vector[i]
            i += 1
        return math.sqrt(sum)

    def unitVector(self):
        print( 1 / (self.magnitude() * self.vector))

vA = [3.183, 7.627]
vec = Vector(vA)
vec.unitVector()
```

Be aware that it does **not** work. Because in `unitVector`, Python doesn't know how to multiply a float by a list (`self.magnitude()` returns a float and `self.vector` is a list). You probably want to rework this part.

Comment: Magnitude doesn't really need a parameter, though

Comment: None of the method really need one

Comment: @cricket_007 if the methods do not need parameters then how would I call them on a specific array?

Comment: If you use Python OOP the right way, then you won't have problems calling the methods with any array you want. I edited my answer.

Comment: @T.Claverie Having only experience in simple java, I was confused about how exactly to use __init__, but I think your answer has cleared it up for me. I'll work on the incompatible types and hopefully get the answer I'm looking for. I appreciate your help!